# Data Structures C#( LinkedList<T> ) vs Our Own Implementation of LinkedList in C#

Tags: c#, performance, memory, data-structures

In Data Structures,C# has its linked-list as Generics, but we can also create our own linked list implementation in C#. Then the question i am asking is if there is any ( performance or memory accessed )difference between them.

Comment: How can anyone guess the performance of *your* code when you don't post it?

Comment: you can use unmanaged code to access memory i.e pointers and add your own implementation

Comment: If you are asking this question, then its a good assumption you need not worry about performance of memory concerns, as anything you write will likely be a worse implementation, less usable and less thought-out than the BCL libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to be generous and assume that what you're really asking is "is there anything special about the implementation of LinkedList in C# that I can't write myself?"

The answer is no. The implementation in the library is written in C#. Here's the source code: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/compmod/system/collections/generic/linkedlist.cs

If you don't like the performance characteristics that this implementation provides, then write your own.

Comment: Since we have the actual source code for the actual implementation of C#'s LinkedList, you can copy/paste it into your solution. If you run it through a profiler you can see for yourself if the performance is the same,